# nyroModal Correct Use Of Options

Tags: jquery, nyromodal

I'm very new to jQuery and just started trying nyroModal tonight. Trying to create some simple popups. I'm working with a popup on page load at the moment. The code I'm trying:

```
$.nmManual('message.html', modal: true);
```

But that doesn't work at all. If I take out `, modal: true` it works, but you can just click to get rid of the window. I also tried `modal='true'` to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The options for nmManual need to be inside curly brackets `{}`.

Your code should look like: `$.nmManual('message.html', {modal: true});`

I've just tested this in jsFiddle with `modal: false` and this seems to work fine. Setting it to true doesn't work but my guess is that this is a restriction of jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yXeYN/